# combining a smaller array (with object elements having key-value pairs) into a larger array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key-value

I have two arrays (initialArray and updatedArray) and both have 18 elements.

Each element in the initialArray is an object with 5 key value pairs.

initialArray:

```
[0]
   head: 'hi',
   a: '',
   b: '',
   c: '',
   d: ''
[1]
   head: 'yo',
   a: '',
   b: 'old',
   c: '',
   d: ''
.
.
.
```

updatedArray is just like initialArray but:
1) it wont have all 5 key values (only between 2 and 3 including head). 
2) initialArray has blank OR old values, whereas updatedArray will be new/populated)
3) the elements are in a different order
e.g.

updatedArray:

```
[0]
   head:'yo',
   b: 'bb',
   d: 'dd'
[1]
   head:'hi',
   b: 'bb',
   a: 'aa'
.
.
.
```

Can someone provide some advice in for overwriting initialArray with the keyvalues from updatedArray (using the 'head' key to match the elements between arrays). The head key is never being updated, but the other key values are.

I would be running this several times when needed, so i can't assume initialArray will always have blank values. If the blank values are not overwritten, then they're retained in the result like below:

combinedArray:

```
[0]
   head: 'hi',
   a: 'aa',
   b: 'bb',
   c: '',
   d: ''
[1]
   head: 'yo',
   a: '',
   b: 'bb',
   c: '',
   d: 'dd'
.
.
.
```

any advice? my current attempt is trying to do something with 3 for loops:

```
    for (var k in updatedArray){
        for (var kk in initialArray){
            if(updatedArray[k].head ==initialArray[kk].head){
                for (var kkk in updatedArray[k][kk]){
                    initialArray[k][kk][kkk] = updatedArray[k][kk][kkk];
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

in this case, k is the index (0,1), kk is the key (head,a,b,etc), and kkk is the value of the key value.although this doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need. The way you are trying to access the properties in the third loop is not correct. See the code below.

```js
var initarray = [{
  head: 'hi',
  a: '',
  b: '',
  c: '',
  d: ''
}, {
  head: 'yo',
  a: '',
  b: 'old',
  c: '',
  d: ''
}]

var updatedarray = [{
  head: 'yo',
  b: 'bb',
  d: 'dd'
}, {
  head: 'hi',
  b: 'bb',
  a: 'aa'
}]

for (var k in updatedarray) {
  for (var kk in initarray) {
    if (updatedarray[k].head == initarray[kk].head) {
      for (var kkk in updatedarray[k]) {
        initarray[kk][kkk] = updatedarray[k][kkk];
      }
    }

  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(initarray));
//console.log(initarray);
```

Hope this Helps :)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I've made an improvement on the previous code. This is the simplest solution I could come up with (Used `Object.assign` for that):

```
updatedArray.forEach(function(update){ 
  var initial = initialArray.find(x => x.head === update.head); 
  Object.assign(initial, update);
});
```

Keep in mind that if the `updateArray` have extra properties, they'll be added as well.